# Issue with ZendeskApi_v2 library in retrieving the top 10 search results

Tags: c#, zendesk-api

I'm using the [ZendeskApi_v2](https://github.com/Speedygeek/ZendeskApi_v2) library to interact with the Zendesk API and retrieve tickets for a specific user. I've encountered an issue while trying to fetch only the top 10 results from the search, and it seems that the `limit` or `per_page` parameters are not behaving as expected.

I have tried using both `limit` and `per_page` in my search query, but it either returns a small number of outdated records or none at all. Without these parameters, I can get a complete list of results, but I'm struggling to limit the results to only the top 10.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
private void SearchTickets(string submitter, int limit = 10)
{    
    string searchTerm = $"submitter:{submitter} order_by:created sort:desc";    

    // How can I properly limit the results to the top 10?
    string limitedSearchTerm = $"{searchTerm} limit:{limit}";
    var results = _api.Search.SearchFor<Ticket>(limitedSearchTerm);

    Console.WriteLine(results.Count);    
}
```